# Complex Django filtering, where filter argument involves comparing two different foreignkey models

Tags: python, django, django-models, filtering, models

Using the below models, imagine five Capacity Instances, each associated to every User and every Question Instance to give independent a question_capacity_value for each capacity per question, and a user_capacity_value for each capacity per user.

I want to generate a queryset of Question instances, and filter it to just leave Question instances where for each capacity the associated question_capacity_value is less than the user_capacity_value in every capacity instance associated with the the question.

In other words each question will have 5 question_capacity values, and the user will have 5 user_capacity values, and I want to exclude questions where for each capacity, the question_capacity_values is less than the user_capacity_value.

```
class Question(models.Model):

    question = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)



class Capacity(models.Model):
    capacity_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.capacity_name)

class UserCapacityValue(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.OneToOneField(Capacity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_capacity_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3, default=0.000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + str(self.capacity.capacity_name) + str(self.user_capacity_value)

class QuestionCapacityValue(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.OneToOneField(Capacity, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    applicable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question_capacity_value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=3, default=0.000)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.question) + str(self.capacity.capacity_name) + str(self.question_capacity_value)
```

Only initial thought (which I'm pretty sure is way off) is:

```
    refined_quetion_qset = targetqset.objects.filter(questioncapacityvalue_set__question_capacity_value__lte=F('???'))
```

No idea what to put in the F function, and imagine this only works if there is one-to-one rather than the one-to-many relation in this case.